# I want to configure nginx so can save from DoS attack

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have configured nginx for my application and want to prevent from DoS attack.
to check it am using this script https://github.com/h0ussni/pwnloris/tree/master.

I have done the below configuration it successfully tackles the attack, but I can see the error '4096 worker_connections are not enough' recently.
I think the open incomplete requests are not closing so the worker connection reaching to configure count.

1. worker processes and CPU affinity are set to auto.
2. worker connections are set to 4096 and nofile rlimit is set to 4096*2
3. using epoll and enabling multi accept too.
4. keep alive timeout is set to 15s and the client header timeout is 2s.

is there any change required in the above configuration?

Or if it will be solved by increasing the worker connection count what should be the value of the worker connection if the CPU core is 26 and the CPU threads are 104?